# Error sending arraylist over socket

Tags: java, sockets, arraylist

I'm getting the error "java.io.NotSerializableException" while trying to send an arraylist of connections over a socket. I've googled the error and read the java page, but I struggling to make sense of it.

im trying to send my array list using this function;

```
public void sendList(Socket clientSocket, ArrayList connections)
{
    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream())) {
        oos.writeObject(connections);
        oos.close();
    }
    catch (IOException error) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + error);
    }

}
```

the arraylist is made up of a class called connections, which stores ip/port/username etc.

Any help is appreciated, ta

Comment: You have to make the class `connections` implement the interface `Serializable`. Serialization requires the explicit implementation of the interface in Java.

Comment: Show your connections class. In addition to implementing `Serializable` you have to make sure all the fields of the class are also serializable.

Comment: What type of object are stored in your `ArrayList`?

Comment: Don't use raw type. Make it parametrized.

Comment: @AntonH yeah I tried implementing it but on the wrong class! it works now - thanks!

Comment: @MikeB Given the brief description of the fields (IP/port/username), I guessed it would be either raw types or String, which is serializable. But good point.